# Loop array into html from setconstant react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tsx

I'm new to react, please don't mind on my questioning format.

I am trying to render an array into html. Stuck in rendering.

```
  const getFullData= (prop: string, filter_data?: any) => {
     let final_array: any = []
    // here my code does some looping and some functionality and pushing the data into above array
    //array will be after pushing the data ["<a href="#"> text1</a>","<a href="#">text2</a>"]
   setfilterConst({...abc,test:final_array}) 
}

<div class="row">     
       {ReactHtmlParser(abc.test)}
</div>
```

but coming with "," . I want to loop and render

Comment: Don't save JSX into component state, this is an anti-pattern in React. Other than this, it's not clear what you are trying to render. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please fill up your question, add the full code of your component. I think you need to build a reduce and then return a React component with your HTML things inside.

Comment: @JavierRojas can you please post some example

Answer (score 0):

Take your array a do a reduce, acc is the variable that is going accumulate (in this example) Cards, when the full loop is done, it is going to set it in the content state, then use `<>{content}</>` at the rendering part.

**data is your array**

```
setContent(
            data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
                let content = ele.content
                let title_name = ele.name
                acc.push(
                    <Card
                        title={title_name}                          
                        className="components_card"
                        key={shortid.generate()}
                    >
                        {ReactHtmlParser(content)}
                    </Card>
                );
                return acc;
            }, [])
        );
```

Comment: Storing JSX in state is anti-pattern in React. Just don't do it. Also, why `.reduce` when `.map` is the function one would use to ***map*** array elements from one value to another?

Comment: Hi Drew thanks for sharing your knowledge, I have been doing this since it works for me. How will you do it? Can you publish an answer with the rigth way? Im really interested to avoid this in future and to correct my codes

Answer (score 0):

Since you are computing and storing an array of JSX you will need to map this array when rendering, passing each element into the `ReactHtmlParser` utility.

```
const getFullData= (prop: string, filter_data?: any) => {
  const final_array: any = [];
  // here my code does some looping and some functionality
  // and pushing the data into above array.
  // array will be after pushing the data:
  //   ["<a href="#">text1</a>", "<a href="#">text2</a>"]
 setfilterConst(abc => ({ ...abc, test: final_array }));
}

...

<div class="row">     
  {abc.test.map((link, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      {ReactHtmlParser(link)}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</div>
```

That being said, it's actually anti-pattern in React to store JSX into component state. You will not want to make a habit of doing this. Instead you should store the data that represents your UI and map to the JSX in the render. Note here that since you are mapping the data to JSX instead of an HTML string you won't need to parse it into renderable HTML.

```
const getFullData= (prop: string, filter_data?: any) => {
  const final_array: any = [];
  // here my code does some looping and some functionality
  // and pushing the data into above array
  // array will be after pushing the data:
  //   [{ text: "text1", href: "#" }, { text: "text2", href: "#" }
 setfilterConst(abc => ({ ...abc, test: final_array }));
}

...

<div class="row">     
  {abc.test.map(({ href, text}, index) => (
    <a key={index} href={href}>{text}</a>
  ))}
</div>
```